# Existe um termo equivalente a 'memoir' em Português?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Existe no português uma expressão equivalente ao inglês *memoir* no sentido usado em Academia — de "an essay on a learned subject"?

O óbvio *memórias* tem um sentido completamente diferente; e também *ensaio* ou *monografia* parecem inapropriados.

Comment: Qual é o sentido de memoir no sentido usada em Academia??  O que segue? do OED): 3. An essay or dissertation on a learned subject closely studied by the writer. In plural also: (the record of) the proceedings or transactions of a learned society.

Comment: @Lambie, leia a pergunta de novo. Ela dá o exato sentido procurado: 'an essay on a learned subject' que é uma das definições do OED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apesar de ter *um* sentido completamente diferente, o óbvio "memória" também tem *um* sentido bastante próximo (além de *outros*):

> Dissertação sobre um tema literário, científico ou erudito destinada a
>   ser apresentada em congresso ou ser publicada em revista
>   especializada. [[Fonte: Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/Memoria/)]

Possíveis alternativas:

- [Apontamento](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/palavra/nBOl/apontamento-2/): Nota, registro ou resumo do que se leu ou se observou; anotação, nota.
- [Tratado](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/Tratado/): Obra que expõe ordenadamente os princípios de uma ciência ou arte.
- [Compêndio](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/comp%C3%AAndio/): Tratado resumido sobre uma ciência, teoria, disciplina etc.

Comment: "Compêndio" is very nice!

Comment: apontamento, notes or records or summary, tratado, treatise, compêndio, compendium (a collection of writings). A única palavra seria memória.

Comment: Conheço um artigo científico denominado [Memória sobre os pesos e medidas em Portugal, Espanha, Inglaterra e França que se empregam nos trabalhos militares](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=e7wLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false), embora date de 1838. Isto indica que *Memória* já foi usado para o equivalente de *memoir*, embora não necessariamente continue sendo usado no Século XXI.